# Eloquent JavaScript Recursion Return?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am having a hard time understanding recursion in Eloquent JavaScript, It easy to know what is happening but I cannot understand why..

```
function power(base, exponent) {
if (exponent == 0)
return 1;
 else
return base * power(base, exponent - 1); /* 2*2*2, this returns only base? 
i thought at first it was, 2*(2,3-1) so it would return 2*(2,2)? 
calling itself until reach 0, so why exponent is out?*/
}

console.log(power(2, 3));
// → 8
```

Comment: It's actually doing `2*2*2*1`

Comment: yeah, why? why is the decreasing exponent there not printed?

Comment: @GlendonPhilippBaculio: What do you mean by "not printed"? The only thing you are printing is the result `8`.

Comment: It's not printed because the exponent is never returned. It's just the internal counter. What was your expected output?

Comment: isn't it suppose to be 2*(2,3-1) so 2*(2,2), 2(2,1), 2(2,0) why is it printed output 2*2*2*1? why is exponent not there? when it is base*power(base,exponen-1)?

Comment: @4catsle: No, actually it calculates `1*2*2*2`. It's recursion, not a loop!

Comment: i am new to javascript and thank you for saying that! i just found The LIFO stack am i rightt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursive functions can often be expressed as a loop. See this adaptation:

```
function power(base, exponent) {
    var result = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < exponent; i++)
        result *= base;
    return result;
}
```

As you can see, the exponent doesn't play a role at all in what is output, it just represents the number of loops to make.

In the world of recursion, the exponent represents the number of times the function has yet to call itself before it can return.

This YouTube video visualizes recursion nicely: [Computerphile](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Mv9NEXX1VHc)

Comment: I didn;t know it also used in return, especially in a function

Comment: @Glendon I don't think you can fully comprehend recursion by understanding loops. Recursion needs the stack!

Comment: @Iven Absolutely, but in this case loops are a great teaching aid, since they use a familiar concept to make an analogy. The analogy isn't perfect of course, or else recursion wouldn't exist.

Comment: for-loops can only represent tail recursion, otherwise they also need a stack-like structure. Since the OP posted a non-tail recursive function you should at least consider that in your "analogy"

Comment: @Iven This question isn't about teaching the OP recursion as a whole, if it was this question would be closed as "too broad". My goal is to answer what they asked, which was simply why the exponent wasn't being output.

Answer (score 1):

First, the recursive function calls build up the stack. Each recursive call reduces the exponent by one, until the base case is reached. The base case requires the exponent to be zero and returns one:

```
power(2,3)
2 * power(2,2)
  … 2 * power(2,1)
      … 2 * power(2,0)
          … 1 // base case is reached
```

Secondly, when the maximum recursion depth is reached, the stack gets unwound. At this point the actual computation takes place:

```
2 * power(2,0) becomes 2 * 1 = 2 is returned
2 * power(2,1) becomes 2 * 2 = 4 is returned
2 * power(2,2) becomes 2 * 4 = 8 is returned
```

Finished, no more stack frames there. 8 is the final result!

Comment: i get that, why is the stack unwound? it's not clear to me, and from the comment it is internal counter?

Comment: When `exponent` is `0`, the base case is reached `if (exponent == 0) return 1;`. This terminates the recursive process, because instead of calling `power` another time, it just returns `1`

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks, much clearer!

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence relation in the question is:

```
p(n) = base * p(n-1)
Expanding, p(n-1) = base * p(n-2)
Expanding, p(n-2) = base * p(n-3)
And so on.. till 
p(1) = base * p(0)
Effectively, it becomes, 
p(n) = base * base ..........n times * 1
```